# what's the difference between semi-supervised learning and partially supervised learning?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, semi-supervised-learning, semi-partial

Isn't every semi-supervised problem also a partially supervised learning problem and vice versa?

Comment: I'm not deeply familiar with either term, but this issue seems to turn on definitions since the plain meanings of "semi-" and "partially" are synonymous. Can you find and provide definitions of both terms?

Comment: Semi-supervised learning is standard terminology, but I'm not familiar with the term "partially supervised learning". It has only 780 hits on google scholar (compared to 62,000 for "semi-supervised learning"). Just briefly perusing, many of them seem to go on to talk about semi-supervised learning (even using that terminology).

Comment: Wiki says that pu-learning is semi-supervised learning where only positive instances are labeled.

Comment: Yes, it's true that "PU" stands for "positive/unlabeled" but what does that have to do with your question?

Comment: I do not find very much other than that. I will just use the term semi-supervised learning. PU-learning doesn't seem popular.